# Why does this sentinel loop keep returning a wrong value?

Tags: c++, while-loop, accumulator

In this program, the program takes two types inputs; numbers and operators and keeps going until the user enters "="
which is the sentinel and marks the end of the expression after which, the program should return the total value of the expression.

A sample run of the program should look something like this:

```
Enter a number followed by an operator and '=' to get the result:
1.0
+
3.4
+
4.8
-
2.3
=
The total value of the expression is 6.9
```

But the output that I am getting is:

```
Enter a number followed by an operator and '=' to get the result:
1.0
+
3.4
+
4.8
-
2.3
=
The total value of the expression is -0.4
```

It seems that when the user inputs `=` the program doesn't seem to know what to do. But I don't know what changes do I make to the code to make it work.

This is my code:

```
// this program finds the value of the expression-
// defined by the sequence of operands and operators
// the user enters a series of numbers and + or - then,
// " = " when finished


#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float total = 0;
    float num;
    char op;
    
    cout << "Enter a number follwed by an operator and '=' to get the result:\n "; 
    cin >> num;
    cin >> op;
    
    while (op != '=')
    {
        if (op == '+')
            {
                total = total + num;
            }
        
        if (op == '-')
            {
                total = total - num;
            }
        cin >> num;
        cin >> op;
    }
    cout << "\nThe total value of the expression is "<< total << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug your own code. Go line by line, observe each variable and see how the execution of the program differs from what you expect at each step.

If you would do that you would see that you apply each operator to the number before it:

| iteration | `num` | `op` | `total` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1st | `1.0` | `+` | `0 + 1 = 1` |
| 2nd | `3.4` | `+` | `1 + 3.4 = 4.4` |
| 3nd | `4.8` | `-` | `4.4 - 4.8 = -0.4` |
| 4th | `2.3` | `=` | while condition `false`, body not entered |

`total` ends up being `-0.4`.

---

What you can do:

- read num
- `total = num`
- loop:

  - read op

    - if op is `=` break
  - read num
  - `total = total op num`

Comment: I am new to programming concepts so, I kindly request you to elaborate your answer.

Comment: I don't believe spoon feeding the answer is helpful, especially to a beginner. If you have specific questions about my answer I'll be happy to answers them, but I won't provide the code since I feel I gave you the necessary information for you to be able to write it.